# Improved bounds in the Berry-Esseen theorem

Tags: pr.probability

One consequence of the Berry-Esseen approach to the Central Limit theorem, states the following. Let $X_1,\ldots ,X_n$ be real valued random variables, all independent, with ${\mathbb E}(X_i) = 0$, ${\mathbb E}(X_i^2) = \sigma _i^2$ 
which satisfies $|X_i| \leq c$ for all $i\in [n]$ and $\sum _{i\in [n]} \sigma _i^2 = 1$. Set $S_n = \sum _{i\in [n]} X_i$. Then for all $t \in {\mathbb R}$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
   {\mathbb P}(S_n \leq t) = {\mathbb P}({\cal Z} \leq t) + O(c),
\end{equation*}
where ${\cal Z}$ is a standard normal random variable. 
My question is simply whether this bound can be improved if we additionally know that ${\mathbb E}(X_i^3) = 0$ for all $i\in [n]$? Intuitively, it seems that this may be improved to
\begin{equation*}
   {\mathbb P}(S_n \leq t) = {\mathbb P}({\cal Z} \leq t) + O(c^2).
\end{equation*} 
Any help / references are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a central limit theorem type result that allows control by moments(via, say Edgeworth expansion), the nature of its proof will not allow a tighter bound. So could you explain how it is "intuitive"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X_i$ which are equally likely to be $n^{-1/2}$ or $-n^{-1/2}$.

These variables are essentially as nice as you could possibly want in terms of moments: The odd moments are all equal to $0$, and $E(|X_i|^k)$ is as small as possible given the variance.

However, the usual Berry-Esseen inequality is sharp up to constants for them ($S_n$ has jumps corresponding to single values taken on with probability proportional to $n^{-1/2}$, while $\mathcal{Z}$ is continuous).

This suggests that, in general, small moments are not in and of themselves enough to improve Berry Esseen.

Comment: On the other hand, if one looks at smoothed versions ${\bf E} F(S_n) = {\bf E} F({\mathcal Z}) + O(c)$ of Berry-Esseen, then more matching moments definitely help; this is easiest to see using the Lindeberg exchange proof of this smoothed version, see e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Terry. I feel slightly stupid having missed this, but I was indeed thinking of matching moments in the Lindeberg exchange proof. The difference between discrete and smooth seem to be key here.

Answer (score 0):

If the random variables have densities, and the third moment is zero, then (provided the fourth moment is finite) the Berry-Esseen theorem holds with rate $1/N$, see for instance

> [S. Johnston - A fast Berry-Esseen theorem (arXiv preprint)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18138).

Edit: Results of this form (often given in terms of Edgeworth-style expansions) are well known in the literature. See for instance Osipov's theorem, Theorem 5.18 of

> *Petrov, Valentin V.*, Limit
> theorems of probability theory. Sequences of independent random
> variables, Oxford Studies in Probability. 4. Oxford: Clarendon Press.
> ix, 292 p. (1995).
> [ZBL0826.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0826.60001).

Theorem 5.18 involves a bound which is only effective when the characteristic function of the random variables has modulus bounded away from $1$ on $\mathbb{R} - [-\delta,\delta]$. This bound is effective whenever the random variables have densities.